# Android WebView Reload when the app loads

Tags: android, webview, restart

I am writing an android application that has a webview.  On the first load it works fine, I am able to browse and drill down to pages.  My expected behavior is that if I leave the application and come back, it should redirect to the page that I have it set to call in the webView.loadUrl("[page i set here]") but it seems to load the page that I was last on when I last used it.

How can I kill the app in the onStop() method? Or, am I supposed to do something else in order  for it to restart the application on every load.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typically in Android, when you leave an app and then come back, the app is expected to be in the same place as when you left.  This allows users to multitask.. I.e., read an email, pick up where they left off in your app.  Why do you want to restart it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will ensure the end of your app with

```
public void finish() {
        super.finish();
}
```

so the next time your webview will load the specified page in your code again

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Mayra, but if you really need this, try to put the logic to the onResume method.

Answer (score 0):

Both of you are right, but for better understanding, I suggest changus to understand this diagram:

http://www.androidside.com/data/geditor/0812/1062731775_4e7c4d93_android+activity+life+cycle.jpg

as well as this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles